# How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin for multiple origin domains with Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, cors

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850482/4375327) on SO to the same nice - and following guidelines - question but for Apache, how to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` entry header for multiple origin domains deals with `.htaccess`, checking from a list of allowed origins and returning the specific value:

```xml
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "<regex-matching-allowed-origin-domains>" \
             AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e \
               env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header merge Vary Origin
</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to do the **same configuration** for **Tomcat**, rather than allowing from any origin as shown below ?

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```